# Can I cast Hellish Rebuke on my turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

The spell requires 1 Reaction to cast on a creature that has damaged me.

In this scenario, let's say I attack a Warlock. He then casts Hellish Rebuke on me as his reaction. In response to his Hellish Rebuke, can I cast Hellish Rebuke on him too, even if it's technically still in my turn? (I don't know whether Reaction can only be used on other player's turn or not)

Comment: Related: [Can a berserker use his reaction for "retaliation" during his turn?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115022)

Comment: Related: [Can you perform a reaction to somebody else's reaction?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70236)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes - you can use a reaction on your turn to cast this if you have one available

> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, **which can occur on your turn** or on someone else's.

Since *hellish rebuke* takes a reaction to cast, it obviously qualifies.

> If a spell can be cast as a reaction, the spell description tells you exactly when you can do so.

The spell specifies that it can be cast

> in response to being damaged by a creature within 60 feet of you that you can see

A common cause of getting damaged on your own turn is getting hit by an opportunity attack as a result of your movement<sup>1</sup>. This would be a valid trigger for the casting of *hellish rebuke*.

So, if it is your turn and you get damaged and you have a reaction you can cast *hellish rebuke* as a reaction.

#### Note: No bonus action spells on your turn before or after *hellish rebuke*

Note that this means that you cannot cast a bonus action spell on your turn after casting *hellish rebuke*. If you have cast a bonus action spell already, you cannot cast *hellish rebuke* during your turn at all<sup>2</sup>. However, casting a bonus action spell on your turn would not affect your ablilty to cast *hellish rebuke* as a reaction outside of your turn. This is confirmed by [Jeremy Crawford here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/721357096055275521).

#### Note: This means you spend your reaction

If you use your reaction on your turn, you are not able to use another one until the start of your next turn<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>thanks @NautArch

<sup>2</sup>thanks @goodguy5

<sup>3</sup>thanks @SteveBauer

Comment: [Relevant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88817/12193)

Comment: As an aside, if you use your reaction on your turn you can't do another reaction till the start of your next turn, I always find it harder to remember when it happens on my turn.